# ReactJS: FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-5

I'm facing the below issue on a ReactJS project (A small project not a complex big one) which is manually configured with **Webpack** and **Babel**. After some time ( 2 - 3 hrs ) this error popped up and if I restart the server it was again normal for a few hrs ( 2 - 3 hrs ). What I'm doing wrong here.

> The same code running smoothly with CRA (creat-react-app) smoothly even for a 10 to 12 hrs of development.

**My node version**
v14.18.1

**My npm version**
v6.14.15

**The Actual error**

```js
<--- Last few GCs --->

[4964:0000012833C0E9A0] 12315086 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 2036.4 (2044.7) -> 2036.4 (2045.7) MB, 90.7 / 0.0 
ms  (average mu = 0.771, current mu = 0.022) last resort GC in old space requested
[4964:0000012833C0E9A0] 12315184 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 2036.4 (2044.7) -> 2036.2 (2045.7) MB, 97.7 / 0.1 
ms  (average mu = 0.620, current mu = 0.000) last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF7C56B412F napi_wrap+133311
 2: 00007FF7C564DD06 SSL_get_quiet_shutdown+63062
 3: 00007FF7C564EB9D node::OnFatalError+301
 4: 00007FF7C5F319CE v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+94
 5: 00007FF7C5F167BD v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize+781
 6: 00007FF7C5DBFFCC v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1516
 7: 00007FF7C5DBB3C1 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateExternalBackingStore+1601
 8: 00007FF7C5DD5155 v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::ShouldDoContextDisposalMarkCompact+1029
 9: 00007FF7C5DD55A5 v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRaw+37
10: 00007FF7C5DE9C1F v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewRawTwoByteString+79
11: 00007FF7C5BDD2B9 v8::internal::String::SlowFlatten+441
12: 00007FF7C5A8BE20 unibrow::Utf8::EncodeOneByte+656
13: 00007FF7C5F3D456 v8::String::Utf8Length+22
14: 00007FF7C566DA67 v8::internal::Malloced::operator delete+21831
15: 00007FF7C5EDE9CF v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle+322591
16: 00007FF7C5EDDF64 v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle+319924
17: 00007FF7C5EDE258 v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle+320680
18: 00007FF7C5EDE0A3 v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle+320243
19: 00007FF7C5FBCEDD v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+474477
20: 00007FF7C5F52FC2 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+40530
21: 00007FF7C5F52FC2 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+40530
22: 00007FF7C5F52FC2 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+40530
23: 00007FF7C5F52FC2 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+40530
24: 00007FF7C5F52FC2 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+40530
25: 00007FF7C5F52FC2 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+40530
26: 00007FF7C5F52FC2 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+40530
27: 00007FF7C5F52FC2 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+40530
28: 00007FF7C5F52FC2 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+40530
29: 000000BB2169DDE5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 134
npm ERR! projectName@1.0.0 start: `webpack serve --config webpack.dev.js `
npm ERR! Exit status 134
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the projectName@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sandy\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-16T07_10_30_417Z-debug.log
```

Here is my code

**package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "something",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This Application created by someone",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --config webpack.dev.js ",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
    "lint": "eslint -c .eslintrc.json --ext .js src --max-warnings=0",
    "format": "prettier --write .",
    "prepare": "npx husky install"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git url"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react",
  ],
  "author": "Someone",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "git url"
  },
  "homepage":  "git url",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.9",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.17.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint": "^8.13.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^7.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.5.0-next-354772952-20220420",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^12.4.0",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "react-dev-utils": "^12.0.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "sass-loader": "^12.6.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.72.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.8.1",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "reactstrap": "^9.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-persist-transform-encrypt": "^3.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "sass": "^1.50.1"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "**/*.{js,jsx}": [
      "npm run lint",
      "npm run format"
    ]
  }
}
```

**webpack.common.js**

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const { WebpackManifestPlugin } = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index: './src/index.js',
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin({
      verbose: true,
      cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: ['**/*', '!manifest.json'],
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html',
      filename: './index.html',
      favicon: './public/favicon.ico',
    }),
    new WebpackManifestPlugin({ fileName: './public/manifest.json' }),
  ],
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)/i,
        use: ['babel-loader'],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|ico)$/,
        use: 'url-loader?limit=100000',
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.jsx', '.js'],
  },
};
```

**webpack.dev.js**

```js
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const openBrowser = require('react-dev-utils/openBrowser');
const common = require('./webpack.common');

const host = process.env.HOST || 'localhost';
const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    onListening: () => {
      openBrowser(`http://${host}:${port}`);
    },
    port,
    host,
  },
});
```

**webpack.prod.js**

```js
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'production',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  optimization: {
    moduleIds: 'deterministic',
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendors',
          chunks: 'all',
        },
      },
    },
    runtimeChunk: 'single',
  },
});
```

**babel.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@babel/react',
    ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }],
  ],
};
```

I have already searched regarding this and somewhere I got an answer to add `--max_old_space_size=4096` this but not able to find where actually where I need to add it.

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command in terminal

```
set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8096
```

Comment: Already tried but no luck